# How to use a custom svelte element with typescript?

Tags: typescript, svelte

I want to use [svelte:element](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/svelte-element) as label and set the "for" attribute. then I get a ts error message, that '"for"' does not exist in type 'HTMLAttributes'
How can I type the svelte:element correctly?

ts error

```
 Object literal may only specify known properties, 
 and '"for"' does not exist in type 'HTMLAttributes<any>'.
```

dynamic svelte element, as label

```
<svelte:element
    this="label"
    for="labelOfInput"
>
   My label
</svelte:element>
```

Comment: I feel like this should just work as is when passing in a constant value. (Though it is pointless to use `svelte:element` if the tag is known, just use `<label ...>`.)

Comment: @H.B. it also can be another element, this is just an example. I was just wondering why there only few ts examples online for svelte.

Comment: It's a really bad example then, because this does not illustrate the issue. If you try this it should work just as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The error was thrown because not every HTML Element has the attribute `for`.

and as the docs indicate:

> `svelte:element` is used when you don't know in advance what kind of DOM element to render.

so if this is not your case and you are sure you will use a label then just use a label, and if not then you should handle the element as generic as possible or just use a svelte component to handle the logic instead.